# Include the primary tag in the title of "Related" questions

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

In the sidebar of Stack Overflow there is a list of **"Related"** questions.

[image: a list of related Stack Overflow questions on programming languages, some including the programming language name such as JavaScript in the title, and some without]

You'll notice that some of these include the programming language in the title and some of them don't. The ones that don't are missing key information - as a user I don't know if these questions are relevant to me and the languages I use currently:

- [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)
- [What is the difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign)

If you click through to the question, you'll find that we have enough confidence in the primary tag to even list it as the HTML title:
[image: the primary tag is listed in the HTML title, showing "python" and "haskell" as prefixes before the question titles]

My suggestion is simply that we include the primary tag before the title in "Related" questions:
[image: a list of related questions prefixed by primary tag such as "Python" or "Haskell"]

Of course there is probably a more visually appealing solution, even re using the tag bubbles from the question page:

[image]

Comment: Why? What problem proposed change is going to solve? What about "Linked" and "Hot Network Questions"?

Comment: *"I don't know if these questions are relevant to me and the languages I use currently"* - honestly "Related" questions are rarely helpful, but clicking either if title sounds useful will not harm while awaiting for answers. If you see question in "Linked" (some user linked it in their response) - you better check it out disregards of language. It could countain language-agnostic answer or give you a concept, clue, etc.

Comment: Consider that many questions are inherently *not* language specific. The language is just the way problem and solution are formulated, but even a passing knowledge of a related language would be enough to understand them.

Comment: I wonder if there's a resource efficient way that a userscript could do this...

Comment: It's not so much a "primary" tag as "the most popular of the tags added to the question". For instance, I might ask a question tagged `html` `css` and `javascript`, it would show up as `javascript` in the list, since `javascript` is the most popular tag, even if my question is actually about what HTML tags I can style using CSS or, in a pinch, JavaScript (and therefore the "primary" tag should be `css` or `html`). But that's an edge case...

Comment: "Consider that many questions are inherently not language specific."
That is true, but in this case, they certainly are. Neither of those two question titles are complete (IMO) without the language tag (one is python specific syntax, the other is haskell specific syntax).
Perhaps a better idea would be to encourage language specific questions to include the language in the title?